# Converting OpenCV to C code

Tags: opencv

I am trying to convert OpenCV application to its pure C code.

Is it possible to write pure c code for the OpenCV application. if Yes where I can find the equivalent C code for OpenCV API

Comment: What do you mean by "pure C code"? Without using OpenCV's libraries?

Comment: Yes. I mean if there is cvtColor in my OpenCV code I want it to be replaced with its C implementation.

Comment: Check out OpenCV code. `cvtColor` and most other functions _are_ internally written in C.

Comment: this sounds like a terrible idea. rather keep the c++ code, and make a c-wrapper around it.

Comment: there is a OpenCV C API (functions like cvCvtColor) but probably not maintained for newer OpenCV versions.

Comment: Thanks, @Micka I was trying to find code of cvCvtColor but couldn't get to it. Do you have any idea on that.

Comment: did you try to just call that function (should be pure C)?

Comment: I am trying to debug into cvCvtColor to get the source code. But no help.

Comment: `cvCvtColor` is defined in the file `<OPENCV_DIRECTORY>/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp`. It is a C-wrapper for the function `cv::cvtColor` also defined in this file. That function has close to 800 lines of code and appears to make use of everything else in that file - including templates and stuff - just so you know what you are up against. ;)